# Manifolds with two coordinate charts

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

What is an early reference for the fact that if a compact, connected $n$-manifold $M$ is covered by two open sets homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $M$ is homeomorphic to $S^n$?

And is it true that if $M$ is a compact, connected $n$-manifold with boundary, and if $M$ is covered by two open sets homeomorphic to $\lbrace(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n  |  x_n \ge 0\rbrace$, then $M$ is a closed ball?

Comment: Lee: I do not see how one could prove this without the annulus theorem, so the earliest reference (say in dimension at least 5) would be Kirby and Siebenmann; in dimension 4 Freedman and Quinn; in dimension 3 and lower I am not sure whom to attribute this result to. 

Comment: The second one follows from the first and the Schoenflies theorem by doubling.

Comment: @Agol: do you mean the Brown-Mazur theorem, i.e. the collared version of the Schoenflies theorem?

Comment: You're looking for something earlier than the Stallings-Zeeman proof of the Poincare conjecture in dims. $\geq 5$ (and I suppose Freedman in dim. 4, Perelman in dim. 3)? 

Comment: Sorry, I meant Newman in 1966 who proved the topological Poincare conjecture (or Smale, depending on which category you're interested in). Clearly your manifold is a homotopy sphere; the question is whether it was identified to be a sphere earlier than the proofs of the Poincare conjecture? 

Comment: I think this problem has some relation to Ljusternik-Schnirelmann category number. Ljusternik-Schnirelmann category number is the minimal number of coordinate that can cover the manifold. In dimension two, if a manifold is not S^2 that the category number is 3. 

I know there is a theorem that the minimal critical point of a function over manifold is bigger than the category number. I don't know whether these two number is equal in other dimension.


Comment: I do not know an early reference for the first result. However, the result is a consequence of the Schoenflies theorem which was published by Morton Brown in 1960.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'll only discuss the first question (**EDIT:** Actually, I address the second question at the end).  As Agol pointed out in the comments, for $n \geq 5$ this is an easy consequence of Newman's 1966 proof of the Poincare conjecture in the topological category.

I don't know if it was explicitly stated earlier than this.  However, it can easily be derived from the main result of the paper

*Brown, Morton*, [**The monotone union of open (n)-cells is an open (n)-cell**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2034881), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 12, 812-814 (1961). [ZBL0103.39305](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0103.39305), [MR0126835 (23 #A4129)](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=126835).

In fact, this works in all dimensions (including $3$ and $4$).

Brown's theorem is as follows.  Assume that $M$ is a topological $n$-manifold and that for all compact $K \subset M$, there exists some open set $U \subset M$ with $K \subset U$ and $U \cong \mathbb{R}^n$.  Then $M \cong \mathbb{R}^n$.  Brown's proof is clever, but completely elementary.

To get the desired result from this, assume that $X = U_1 \cup U_2$ with $U_i \cong \mathbb{R}^n$ and that $X$ is compact.  Let $\phi : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow U_1$ be a homeomorphism.  It is enough to prove that $X \setminus \{\phi(0)\} \cong \mathbb{R}^n$.  We will do this with Brown's theorem.  Consider a compact set $K \subset X \setminus \{\phi(0)\}$.  To verify Brown's criteria, it is enough to construct a homeomorphism $\psi : X \setminus \{\phi(0)\} \rightarrow X \setminus \{\phi(0)\}$ such that $\psi(K) \subset U_2$.

For $r>0$, let $B(r) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be the ball of radius $r$.  The set $U_1 \setminus U_2$ is compact, so there exists some $R>0$ such that $U_1 \setminus \phi(B(R)) \subset U_2$.  Also, there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $K \cap \phi(B(\epsilon)) = \emptyset$.  It is easy to construct a homeomorphism $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(B(\epsilon)) = B(2R)$ and $f(0)=0$ and $f|_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B(3R)} = \text{id}$.  We can therefore define a homeomorphism $\psi : X \setminus \{\phi(0)\} \rightarrow X \setminus \{\phi(0)\}$ by $\psi(p) = \phi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}(p)$ for $p \in U_1 \setminus \{\phi(0)\}$ and $\psi(p) = p$ for $p \notin U_1$.  Clearly $\psi(K) \subset U_2$.

---

**EDIT:** Lee suggested that this might be able to address his second question too.  I thought a bit about it, and I believe that it can.  The key is the following "relative" version of Brown's theorem, which can be proven exactly like Brown's theorem.

Theorem : Let $(M,N)$ be a pair consisting of a topological $n$-manifold $M$ and a closed submanifold $N \subset M$.  Assume that for all compact $K \subset M$, there exists some open set $U \subset M$ such that $K \subset U$ and such that the pair $(U,U \cap N)$ is homeomorphic to the pair $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^{n-1})$ (the second embedded in the standard way).  Then $(M,N) \cong (\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^{n-1})$.

To apply this, assume that $X$ is a compact manifold with boundary and that $X = U_1 \cup U_2$ with $(U_i,\partial U_i) \cong (\mathbb{R}^n_{\geq 0},\mathbb{R}^{n-1})$.  Double $X$ to get a closed manifold $Y$, and let $Y' \subset Y$ be the image of the boundary of $X$.  The open sets $U_i$ double to give an open cover $Y = V_1 \cup V_2$.  Letting $V_i' = V_i \cap Y'$, we have $(V_i,V_i') \cong (\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^{n-1})$.  Let $(M,M')$ be the result of deleting the image of $0$ in $(V_1,V_1')$.  It is enough to prove that $(M,M') \cong (\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^{n-1})$, and this can be proven just like above.

---

Of course, Agol answered the second question first -- it follows from the topological Schonfleiss theorem applied to the double, which was proven by Brown in

*Brown, Morton*, [**A proof of the generalized Schoenflies theorem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1960-10400-4), Bull. Am. Math. Soc. 66, 74-76 (1960). [ZBL0132.20002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0132.20002), [MR0117695 (22 #8470b)](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=117695).

Mazur had earlier proven a weaker result.  This requires the sphere to be bicollared, but this holds.  Indeed, from the assumptions the sphere is locally bicollared, and Brown proved in

*Brown, Morton*, [**Locally flat imbeddings of topological manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1970177), Ann. Math. (2) 75, 331-341 (1962). [ZBL0201.56202](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0201.56202), [MR0133812 (24 #A3637)](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=133812).

that this implies that the sphere is bicollared.  See

*Connelly, R.*, [**A new proof of Brown’s collaring theorem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2037284), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 27, 180-182 (1971). [ZBL0208.50704](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0208.50704), [MR0267588 (42 #2490)](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=267588).

for a super-easy proof of Brown's collaring theorem.

Comment: If Brown's clever proof works for a closed half-space in place of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then your proof would extend to answer my second question as well.

Comment: @Lee Mosher : Something like that works!  I added it in an edit.

Comment: Very nice. I would accept Ian Agol's comment too if I could.

Comment: For a different reference, the proof in this answer of the first statement appears in theorem 2.7 of [Steve Ferry's geometric topology notes](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sferry/ps/geotop.pdf).